Acknowledgement and retry mechanism for Java MDB Listener if forced stopped
I have an MDB listener on an IBM MQ queue in IBM WAS server. MDB receives the message and do the processing and updates the database. These is one problematic scenario that I am unable to handle.
In case when a message arrived at MDB listener and it's middle of processing, if someone forced stop the MDB application or restarts entire server note, the message under process will be lost from the queue without finishing the process. Is there any mechanism to avoid such scenario. I tries to use CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT with message.acknowledge() but it didn't work.
My MDB is like this:
@MessageDriven(name = "queueMDB", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
}
public class TestMdb implements MessageListener {

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext messageDrivenContext;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            // Some usefull code...
            message.acknowledge()
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                messageDrivenContext.setRollbackOnly();
            }
        }
    }

My ibm-ejb-jar.xml look like below:
<ejb-jar-bnd
        xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_2.xsd"
        version="1.0">

    <message-driven name="TestMdb">
        <jca-adapter activation-spec-binding-name="jms/TestQueueAS" destination-binding-name="jms/TestQueue"  />           
    </message-driven>
</ejb-jar-bnd>

Can anyone please help me solve this issue, If only I get the acknowledgement working, I will acknowledge every message, in case of forced stop, the queue message will not be acknowledged and will not be deleted from actual queue. That message will be processed once the MDB is up again.

from the code and config you have shown, it looks like the application is using Bean managed transactions. If so, the point at which you call acknowledge the message will be removed from the queue. It seems that behaviour you would like is container managed transactions. This would mean that the message gets automatically rolled-back by WAS if the MDB doesn't complete its onMessage method processing.

Take a look at this doc > https://www.ibm.com/docs/ru/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=retrieval-message-driven-beans-transaction-support < for more information on WAS / IBM MQ JMS transactions.

Thanks for you reply. I have read the documentation but I am unable to find any working example of  Message redelivery, transaction handling in context of IBM MQ and IBM Websphere. Can you please suggest some code example as well?

from my understanding of the spec, message.acknowledge() will be ignored if your application is container managed. I think it's worth clarifying a few things:
Are you using persistent or non-persistent messages?
When you restart the server node, does that include the queue manager?
What's the value of UNCOM on the queue you are working with when you run DISPLAY QSTATUS('YOUR_QUEUE') on your queue manager?
Have you set TransactionAttributeType anywhere in your ejb-jar.xml file or via any other annotations?

Also worth taking a look at this doc > https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=scenarios-expiring-global-units-work <. It's possible that WAS forcibly restarted in the very early phase of a transaction and the queue manager is waiting for XA recovery. In this case the message would not be visible. Common values are AMQ_TRANSACTION_EXPIRY_RESCAN=30000 and AMQ_XA_TRANSACTION_EXPIRY=60000

did you make any progress?

For Container Managed transactions, there should be no need to acknowledge the message as it will be removed from the queue when the MDB onMessage method completes. In the event of an exception or failure during normal onMessage processing, the message will be rolled-back to the queue and the JMSXDeliveryCount of the message will be incremented. The message will then be consumed by an new MDB instance to retry processing.
In this scenario WAS is coordinating a transaction with IBM MQ and potentially other transactional resources. During MDB processing, WAS is forcibly stopped or the host server is restarted. On recovery, WAS will attempt to replay any 'in-flight transactions' and resolve units of work that have advanced to the initial prepare phase.
Meanwhile messages on the queue that are considered as being part of a transaction by IBM MQ, but not necessarily considered 'in-flight' by the transactional coordinator, will not visible. There are two environment variables that determine IBM MQ's handling of messages in this state; AMQ_TRANSACTION_EXPIRY_RESCAN (how often the queue manager should check for transactions marked as expired) and AMQ_XA_TRANSACTION_EXPIRY (how long the queue manager should wait before marking a transaction as expired), and are described in this documentation. Common values are AMQ_TRANSACTION_EXPIRY_RESCAN=30000 and AMQ_XA_TRANSACTION_EXPIRY=60000
To set these environment variables on the system hosting your queue manager:
export AMQ_TRANSACTION_EXPIRY_RESCAN=30000
export AMQ_XA_TRANSACTION_EXPIRY=60000

